# Positive and Negative Button position on a DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

Is there any way to change the order on which the positive, negative and neutral buttons are shown in a `DialogFragment` so that I can put for instance the negative button first?

I don't want to change the "nature" of the button but keep them being "positive", "negative" and "neutral".

Comment: Just declare them in order you want to show them, positive, neutral, negative...

Comment: mmm... I agree with @Stanojkovic... or maybe using a custom dialog?

Comment: Yep, as simple as that, thanks @Stanojkovic, I should've thought about that, it is a builder after all :)

Comment: BTW, @Stanojkovic if you post your answer I can flag it as the solution...

Comment: Ok, here it is, thank you @Carlos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try like this:**

```
builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
           .setPositiveButton()
           .setNeutralButton()
           .setNegativeButton()
```

Comment: Well, after trying, it just won't put the buttons in the order I want for some reason ....

Answer (score 2):

Declare the button in order you want:

- On devices prior to Honeycomb, the button order (left to right) was POSITIVE - NEUTRAL - NEGATIVE.
- On newer devices using the Holo theme, the button order (left to right) is now NEGATIVE - NEUTRAL - POSITIVE.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most elegant of ways but it will do what you want

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SUtils.getContext());
        builder.setMessage("Confirmation?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //TOdo
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //TOdo
                }
            })


        diaglog = builder.create();
```

Just make the Cancel button as positive and the Ok button as negative.

Answer (score 0):

Since you typically create a custom XML layout for a DialogFragment, you can create the button(s) you want there and place them wherever you want in the layout.

Then instead of using positive, neutral, or negative buttons, you can just get your buttons (via their Id-s), give them onClick listeners to do whatever you want.